# Using UnitOfWork for Business logic?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-of-work

Im trying to understand when and how to use UOW in the "correct way".. I know there is most likely a bunch of right and wrong ways of doing it and in some cases it might come down to such a things as "flavour"..

Anyway.. the thing I dont get is that for a couple of months ago I joined a project where they were using UOW for the business logic as well.. which after reading a few posts about it doesnt seem to make much sense.. since from what I have understod UOW's primary purpose is to handle the "transactions" from your application to the datasource(database), correct?

So for instance in DDD your repositories would be a part of the UOW since you want to keep the DbContext(Database connection) open for quite some time so you can share the same DbContext between multiple repositories and then in one single transaction execute all the changes to the same DbContex... which makes sense I guess..

But placing for instance Services or Factories (In a DDD) as a part of your UOW wouldnt make much sense.. since they are not(or at least shouldnt) interact with any DbContext or database..

So... would it be ok to "bundle up" Buisness Logic with the UOW?..
So for instance:

```
var html = UnitOfWork.HtmlFactory.EncodeString("<p>some string</p>");
UnitOfWork.HtmlStringRepository.Add(html);
UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

Would that even make sense?

Wouldnt it make more sense to do:

```
var html = HtmlFactory.EncodeString("<p>some string</p>");
UnitOfWork.HtmlStringRepository.Add(html);
UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

??

Oh!..and the UnitOfWork is a property in this case.. so yes.. its an object-reference, not a class with a bunch of static functions.

Br,
Inx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, UnitOfWork should'nt have business logic as part of it, it only should care about transaction boundary.

Also if u are implementing any encode logic i would create a Value object EncodedHtml since it represents something meaningful for the business. like this

```
public class EncodedHtml
{
    public string Html {get; private set;}

    public EncodedHtml(string htmlToEncode){
        Html = EncodeHtml(htmlToEncode);
    }

    private string EncodeHtml(string htmlToEncode){
        // code 
        return htmlEncoded;
    }
}
```

Now everywhere i see this ValueObject i know its been encoded and validated so i can atach it to my entity in this case HtmlString(not sure).

Comment: Thank you for making this clear :)
The sample code was more for the purpose of demonstraiting my point, and not an actual implementation, but yes, making a value object of the Html Encoding makes alot of sense :)

Answer (score 1):

> A Unit of Work keeps track of everything you do during a business transaction that can **affect the database**. When you're done, it figures out everything that needs to be done to **alter the database as a result of your work**.

The quote is from [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html), but I've added the highlight. I have only seen the Unit of Work pattern with data access code, which shouldn't normally (probably ever) contain any business logic.

So I think your understanding is correct, and the example code does look strange.

Have you asked your team what they were trying to achieve?